# POST Request with python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I've buid an API that receives a GET request like: `/myapi.com/login?username=me&password=mypass` and gives me a unique token. With that token I in headers i can send an email by the API. The problem is that i am authentified, i receive my token, I put it in the header for a post request nut I can't send emails : the server says : "500 internal error full authentification is required to access this ressource"

There's my python script :

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

import requests
import json
import unirest

# Connection  
payload = {'username':'monusername', 'password':'monpassword'}
r = requests.get('monapi.com/login', params=payload)
print(r.url, r.content, r.json, r.status_code)
# Recup the token
token = json.loads(r.text)
token = str(token['token'])
# we want to send an email
payload2 = {'from': 'v.test@outlook.com', 'to': 'v.test@outlook.com', 'subject': 'test de mon script', 'content': 'salutations vous etes le premier a recevoir un de mes emails'}
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'token': token}
r2 = requests.post('monapi.com/front/fSend', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload2))

print(r2.status_code,r2.request.headers, r2.request.body)
```

And the server response is :

```
(u'monapi.com/login?username=monusername&password=monpassword', '{"name":"monusername","password":"86057438fbc6889b91f258c30d1da4db8d71d7c8","token":"a89ba0ac6885668e2d7d983c36af845e","id":1}', <bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>, 200)
(500, {'Content-Length': '180', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1', 'token': 'a89ba0ac6885668e2d7d983c36af845e', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, '{"content": "salutations vous etes le premier a recevoir un de mes emails", "to": "v.tests@outlook.com", "from": "v.tests@outlook.com", "subject": "test de mon script"}').
```

Everything works using CORS extension RESTClient but not on my server....

Comment: Do you get any errors? It might be related to CORS.

Comment: It is not directly related but the error should not be 500 since it is a status code reserved for internal error from which server can't recover.
The authentification problem is an other http response.
Could we see the server side code  ?

Comment: I've built the API with Symfony2 so, symfony says that my code 500 is related to authentication fail. I've the same with the chrome extension : chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/RestClient.html when have a bad token.